# How to get nodal values in OpenFOAM?

Tags: paraview, openfoam

I would appreciate knowing how I can convert the cell values given after the OpenFOAM solution into the ones on the grid points. Is there any direct command for such a thing or I should work with the sampling option?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Do you need nodal values to use sampling or for the entire computational domain?

Comment: Dear @s.ouchene, Thanks for your response.  Yes, the entire domain is of my interest. I am actually looking for a set of data on the grid points of the mesh rather than the cell values in a form of "x_p y_p U_p T_p" where for example T_p is the temperature value at the pth grid point. I need this data-set to do some model reduction afterward.

Comment: Do you want those values on Paraview?

Comment: That would be also great to have them in Paraview. Can I extract this data in a file?

Comment: You can export your data from Paraview as CSV file if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open your case using Paraview/paraFoam, then the interpolated fields at the points (nodes) are already computed by Paraview:

[image]

Fields with an orange small circle are the point data, while the fields that have an orange cube icon are the data at the cell centers, i.e:

[image: types of fields]

You can also see the values of the fields (points or cell) using the Spreadsheet view and export them as CSV:

[image]

Comment: Be careful that this approach will not give the values at the points that OpenFOAM was using, paraview doesn't know anything about the discretization/interpolation scheme employed to get nodal values in OpenFOAM.